# Dependency development in IntelliJ IDEA and gradle builder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

There are two projects in gitlab:

- project-a
- project-a-dependency

In **project-a**, **project-a-dependency** is a dependency that is connected as:

`implementation("my.space:project-a-dependency")`

Currently, the development is carried out as follows:

- Changes are being made to **project-a-dependency**
- The assembly is done and sent to the nexus
- I open the **project-a** project and pull down the new version of project-a-dependency

Question: is there any way to open two projects simultaneously in IntelliJ IDEA, change the dependency, rebuild the project and see all the changes? If the answer is yes, then how do I do it?

I tried the following:
Project -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> [+]
I added the **project-a-dependency** module and clicked the "apply" button.

Then I added it to build.gradle the line:

`implementation project(':project-a-dependency')`

I clicked the "Load gradle changes" button and got an error:

> Project with path ':project-a' could not be found in root project 'project-a-dependency'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and project-a-dependency is a standalone Gradle project you can achieve this with a composite build.

> A module dependency can be substituted by a dependency to a local fork of the sources of that module, if the module itself is built with Gradle.

Add the dependency on project-a-dependency inside your `settings.gradle.(kts)` with the help of `includeBuild()` function. Included builds are added by location. This will allow you to work with your project-a-dependency as if it were just a module in your current project. Dependency substitution will be handled by Gradle for you.

> One thing to note is that since your dependency is local it will have to be compiled instead of just being an available binary

More info: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#defining_composite_builds

Comment: Happy to help. One more thing to note is that there are two types of included builds. Included builds for plugins and for projects. If you ever need to develop a Gradle plugin make sure to call includeBuild function inside pluginManagement block to make it available to your build scripts